# Shibboleth SP and ADFS as idP

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, adfs, shibboleth

I have a java web application and I need to implement SAML SSO to allow authentication from customer's ADFS.
And I have a quick basic question (generally about Shibboleth SP):
Is it possible to connect Shibboleth SP directly to AFDS as idP? Or having both SP and IdP on my java-side (to configure federation between the IdP and the ADFS IdP) is the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can - much along these lines: [AD FS 2.0 Step-by-Step Guide: Federation with Shibboleth 2 and the InCommon Federation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg317734(v=ws.10).aspx).